# Xamarin Forms MvvmCross binding a button command error

Tags: xamarin, button, command, mvvmcross

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms MvvmCross project. I'm binding a common button command on the view with a IMvxAsyncCommand on the view model, as follows:

- View

  ```
   <views:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:views="clr- namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                     x:Class="TestProject.Pages.TestPage">
   <ContentView>
       <StackLayout>
           <Button Text="Test the command!" Command="{Binding TestAsyncCommand}"/>
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentView>
  ```

  </views:MvxContentPage>
- View model

  ```
   namespace TestProject.ViewModels
   {
       public class TestViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
       {
           public TestViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
               : base(logProvider, navigation)
           {
           }

           public IMvxAsyncCommand TestAsyncCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await TestAsyncCommandMethod());

           private async Task TestAsyncCommandMethod()
           {
               //await some stuff
           }
       }
   }
  ```

Anythings seems to work fine but rarely sometimes after a pression of the button it becames disable. What could happen? It does not happen if I use Command in place of MvxAsyncCommand, like here:

```
public Command TestAsyncCommand => new Command(async () => await TestAsyncCommandMethod());
```

Note: TestAsyncCommandMethod is entirely encased in a try-catch block to avoid possible exceptions.

Comment: What does `TestAsyncCommandMethod()` look like?

Comment: var ret = await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(...);
if (!ret)
 return;
ret = await BackgroundBleCommunication();
if (!ret)
 await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(...);

Comment: `Command` is from native Xamarin.Forms,but `IMvxAsyncCommand` is from  `MvvmCross`.By the way, Suggest that using `public IMvxAsyncCommand TestAsyncCommand { get; private set; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong here is that instead of creating a Property to Bind the View and the ViewModel you are using a field can you try this:

```
public IMvxAsyncCommand TestAsyncCommand {get; set;}
```

And then in your constructor do this:

```
public TestViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        : base(logProvider, navigation)
    {
      TestAsyncCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await TestAsyncCommandMethod());
    }
```

### UPDATE

This seems to be a bug with MvvmCross! 
Issue can be found in the added link

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1589

Comment: I tried but your solution doesn't resolve the issue. I think it's a sort of MvxAsyncCommand bug on Android. Your solution replacing MvxAsyncCommand with Command works perfectly as mine

Comment: I found this MvvmCroos issue report: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1589

Comment: As I understand from the issues, this issue is still active?

Comment: Now the issue is resolved also if I still prefer to use Command